# Symony 5 PHP : Possible solutions handling whitelabel routes

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I've come back to Symfony after a long time in order to make things more accessible for other developers and properly integrate it in someone else's project.
The problem I'm facing is that my project uses whitelabels and it's hard for me to find the proper solutions online.
I am using Symfony 5 at the moment.

It looks like the Locale Prefixes to routes could have been a good solution, but probably this should only work with locales and not with whitelabels. I couldn't really find an answer how to use prefixes differently.
The amount of whitelabels can increase over time and I'd prefer not a hardcoded solution. I rather add whitelabels in configuration and/or database.
I'm also trying to re-code my project as a bundle in Symfony.

At the moment I've found 2 possible options: Using a routes.php in the bundle or adding a Controller action for each of the whitelabels, which forwards the request to the proper controller.
The main controller action routes are mapped by annotation/attributes in the controllers, like:

```
/**
 * @Route("/mainlabel/test", name="mainlabel_test")
 * @return Response
 */
```

But the problem with the 'routes.php solution' is that I want to get a list of all available routes, so I can 'copy' the whitelabel routes next to the 'mainlabel' routes. I can't figure out at the moment how to get a list of the routes, if this is even possible at the time of route configuration.
It would be a more dynamic version of the following:

```
// config/routes.php
use App\Controller\TestController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\Configurator\RoutingConfigurator;

return static function (RoutingConfigurator $routes): void {
    $labels = ['whitelabel_alpha', 'whitelabel_beta', 'whitelabel_gamma'];
    
    foreach ($labels as $label) {
        $routes->add("{$label}_test", "{$label}/test")
            ->controller([TestController::class, 'test'])
        ;
    }
};
```

I'd figure I can just write a Service or something to handle the whitelabel's differences.

The other solution I had in mind was to create a controller action for each whitelabel. It would be partially hardcoded this way, but might be a more feasible/common solution:

```
/**
 * @Route("/whitelabel_alpha")
 * @Route("/whitelabel_alpha/{action}")
 * @Route("/whitelabel_alpha/{action}/{id}")
 * @return Response
 */
public function whitelabelAlpha(string $action=null, int $id=null): Response
{
    $params = [];
    $route = 'mainlabel';
    if (!empty($action) ) {
        $route .= '_' . $action;
    }
    if (!empty($id) ) {
        $params['id'] = $id;
    }
    try {
        $url = $this->generateUrl($route, $params);
        
        $response = $this->forward('Bundle/Controller/TheRightController::theRightAction', $params);
        return $response;
    } catch (RouteNotFoundException) {
    }
}
```

I only couldn't really find a solution on how to get the controller/action by a route name. Pretty much all search results were for the opposite. (how to get a route by controller/action)

I apologize beforehand in case my question isn't formulated/formatted properly. First time question. Happy to hear any comments/criticism how to improve.

Answer (score -1):

You first solution sounds good to me as a great way of doing it.
You're facing complex issue that im not aware of so i will try a "simple" approach.  Improve your question if you want me to improve my answer.

#### You do not need a route for each white label

Just build your route like `/{whitelabelname}/{action}/{id}`

#### You do not need a controller for each action

Controller return a response. So dont do more controller. Just build the response in a class according to your whilabel action and return it to your controller. But dont bother yourself with multiple controller.

#### You need a specific "service" or class that should build a response according to your whitelabel

2 options :

If you always code the new whitelabel its easy. Just make an enum that refer all the needed class for your whitelabel according to route param.

If there is a incremental amount of whitelabel that you do not know who can add it or when. This is much harder.
You will need to store it in database and have kind of a configuration linked to it.

My main question to be able to improve your answer :
Why it look like all your whitelabel feature differ from one whitelabel to another ?

---

From my point of view, `whitelabel A` `feature A` do the exact same things than `whitelabel B` `Feature A`
Only the data returned differ because the owner is different.
In that case, you do not even need multiple "service" to return the proper data in your controller

Comment: The general features of each whitelabel are identical. There's minor differences, like a product option not available for whitelabel A or only specifically available for whitelabel B. I imagined solving this with a service that checks the whitelabel part of the URL.

I didn't specify why I didn't want to use a general route like : /{whitelabelname}/{action}/{id}
However unlikely, it is possible that I might share similar routes to the one developing the main project.
Preferably I would like to use a yaml configuration to define the whitelabels (custom logo and such).